# get magento current url by store id

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I have many pages which has different url key for different stores. Can I get current URL on basis of store ID. function I am using right now is `getCurrentUrl()`.

I mean let suppose i have two stores en and fr. Now I have a page with 2 url

```
(page-en.html, page-fr.html).
```

Right now let suppose i am at

```
page-en.html
```

so if I write something like getCurrentURL(fr) then I should get

```
site_url/page-fr.html.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
```

http://jagdeepbanga.com/blog/magento-get-base-url-skin-url-media-url-js-url-store-url-and-current-url.html